# Optional viewport in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm setting up an app with multiple viewports. However I want one of the viewports to be optional, i.e. if the viewport is not defined in a certain route, it should simply not render. However, Aurelia throws an error if I try to do that. Is there another way to make a viewport optional?

Answer (score 2):

if there's no built-in support in aurelia for this you could configure the unneeded viewport point to a module that has the following logic:

```js
import {noView, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView
@inject(Element)
export class HiddenViewPort {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  activate() {
    // hide the router-view element
    this.element.parentNode.classList.add('aurelia-hide');
  }

  deactivate() {
    // show the router-view element
    this.element.parentNode.classList.remove('aurelia-hide');
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this still valid?

First, the `@noView`  decorator leads to an error but I could do it with an empty (inlineView) template.

My problem is: the injected element is not the parent of the `<router-view>` element (as I would expect) but the element which has `aurelia-app` set. Thus `aurelia-hide` is assigned to its parent, which is `<body>` in my case.

I've reproduced this in a gist.run: https://gist.run/?id=54748b3d8043726168a7b76d99a5865e
If you have a look at it, the `aurelia-hide` class is set on the `<html>` element.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, optional viewports are not supported. Our workaround is to use an *empty* module, without any content:

```
import {inlineView} from 'aurelia-templating';

@inlineView('<template></template>')
export class EmptyViewModel {
}
```

Comment: Using `@noView` would have the same effect